# How can i access through ssh spring shell cli

Tags: java, docker, ssh, command-line-interface, spring-shell

I am trying to implement a simple cli application ( executable jar file running in linux docker image) using spring-shell library. After i started the Docker image with "docker run -it -p 8080:8080 springshelldemo" command my spring-shell app starts and the cli is available in cmd. How can i access this spring-shell cli from a second cmd using docker exec command (or some other better way) ?
I need this in order to make my app available to more than 1 users at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this problem. There is this great library on top of spring shell https://github.com/fonimus/ that gives you ssh functionality and with proper docker run file command you can access the spring shell through ssh with all features present.